# Extension can't find view or template

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I followed [Creating a first extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/Index.html) tutorial very carefully. I get error when viewing the page with the plugin.

> Sorry, the requested view was not found.
>
> The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "display" in class "MyVendor\Chat\Controller\ChatController".

The controller:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\Chat\Controller;
class ChatController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {
    public function displayAction() {
    }
}
?>
```

[This screenshot shows directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C30XS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you name the file Display.html and see if it works then?

Comment: Thanks, this is it.